# Change Icon on onReceive method - widget Android

Tags: android, icons, widget

I developed a widget for Android with the intention of clicking a text widget's icon is changed. To do this I set the action and I have tried the method OnReceive action. This is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_NOTIF)) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
            RemoteViews controles = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widgetcuatroxuno);
            controles.setImageViewResource(R.id.btt,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_new);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, controles);
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }

    }
```

I know I need AppWidgetManager to update the widget controls, but it failed. How I can fulfill my purpose? Sorry for my English. Thank you very much for everything.

Comment: <br/> if someone have the same problem, i found the solution:

    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      RemoteViews control= new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
        R.layout.widget);
      if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_CHANGE)) {
       control.setImageViewResource(R.id.bttn,
         R.drawable.ic_launcher_new);
      } else {
       super.onReceive(context, intent);
      }
      ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
      AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, control);
     }

Answer (score 3):

```
RemoteViews control = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);
            control.setTextViewText(R.id.textview1, "ExampleText");

            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context,
                    ButtonWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn,
                    control);
```

This one works in OnReceive(), thanks a lot!

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'ButtonWidget'. How can I solve it?